# Trying to run a regression on the number of early decision students enrolled in a given year. Does anyone know where I can get that data?

Tags: collegescorecard

Hi is there a database that contains early decision enrollee information?

Could really use the help here, thanks.

Comment: Hi. The wikipedia article on early admission provides some data about that, aggregated from various sources. Look at the tables in the section "Admit rates and enrollment statistics" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Early_decision#Admit_rates_and_enrollment_statistics On the other hand, you don't give a lot of info about what other kind of data you'd need for your regression, so hard to tell if it will be enough for your purpose.